# Mockito for EntityManager persist method call failed

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have code which uses `persist()` method of EntityManager. I am using SpringBoot with Mockito for my unit testing.

**Source.java**

```
public class Operation {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public addOperation(List<Operation> operationList) {
        for(Operation operation : operationList) {
            entityManager.persist(operation);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class OperationTest {

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    Operation sut;

    List<Operation> operationList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        List<Operation> operationList = new ArrayList<>();
        Operation operation1 = new Operation();
        Operation operation2 = new Operation();

        // Add operations to the list 
        operationList.add(operation1);
        operationList.add(operation2);
    }

    @Test
    public void  importFileSuccessful() {

        doNothing().when(entityManager).persist(any(Operation.class));
        sut.addOperation(operationList);
    }
}
```

**Issue :**

When I run the test code, it is successfully passed. However, instead of mocking `persist()` method of EntityManager, my code is adding the data to the real database.

**Questions :**

1. Do I need any special code to handle the entityManager annotated with @persistenceContext in source code?
2. What am I missing in the mocking for test class so that actual persist method is not called and mock is called?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense to use Spring in unit tests. Remove that and only use Mockito. That might already fix your issue.

Comment: Well if you're testing a Spring based application it makes sense to use Spring to substitute specific beans with mocks to eliminate external dependencies in testing. Spring boot testing provides [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) and [@TestConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html). Section 5 of this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) has a concise example.

Comment: I should also note that if you're already using spring boot you can use Spring Data JPA to generate DAOs rather than writing save methods in your entity classes. Another [article](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa) for reference.

Comment: @patonw When you're writing something like integration tests, then yes you can use Spring testing libraries, but when writing unit tests, it doesn't bring anything helpful to the table. A mocking framework is all you need there.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I have not got the answer to the question of what do I need to change in my code to fix the issue?

Comment: Like I said in my first comment: Kick Spring stuff out of your test class and build it solely on using Mockito (lucky you, you did that already, just prevent Spring from messing with Mockito). That will fix your issue.